# Linq to XML, drilling down the attributes

Tags: linq-to-xml, serialization, attributes

I have an XML which looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Applicant>
  <NameValueGroup attribute="Name">
    <NameValue desc="One" value="test1"/>
    <NameValue desc="Two" value="test2"/>
    <NameValue desc="Three" value="test3"/>
    <NameValue desc="Four" value="test4"/>
  </NameValueGroup>
  <NameValueGroup attribute="News">
    <NameValue desc="news1" value="Something1"/>
    <NameValue desc="news2" value="Something2"/>
    <NameValue desc="news3" value="Something3"/>
    <NameValue desc="news4" value="Something4"/>
  </NameValueGroup>
</Applicant>
```

How will I write a LINQ to XML query to deserialize this XML.

Comment: dear @unknown(google): you need to **highlight** your XML sections and click on the "code" button (010 101) on the toolbar to make those sections visible - otherwise we won't see anything at all.

Comment: What do you have? We won't write your code for you.

Comment: I am having hard time to figure out how to get the elements with attributes.

I tried something like this

var query = from p in xml.Descendants("Applicant")
select new {
           p.Element("NameValueGroup").Element("NameValue").Attribute("desc").value
           }).tolist();
but it does not work.

Comment: lakario it is not homework, I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This works but it has no error handling for empty/missing values. Enjoy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace LinqToXmlExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = XDocument.Load("input.xml");

            var content =
                from node in x.Descendants("Applicant").Descendants("NameValueGroup")
                select new NameValueGroup()
                           {
                                Attribute = node.Attribute("attribute").Value,
                                NameValues = GetNameValues(node.Descendants())
                           };

            foreach (NameValueGroup item in content)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute);
                foreach (var name in item.NameValues)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", name.Desc, name.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static List<NameValue> GetNameValues(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
        {
            var x = new List<NameValue>();
            if(elements != null && elements.Any())
            {
                x =
                    (from node in elements
                    select new NameValue()
                               {
                                   Desc = node.Attribute("desc").Value,
                                   Value = node.Attribute("value").Value
                               }).ToList();
            }
            return x;
        }

        class NameValueGroup
        {
            public string Attribute { get; set; }
            public List<NameValue> NameValues { get; set; }
        }

        class NameValue
        {
            public string Desc { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tip about handling missing values: rather than using XAttribute.Value, use the explicit conversion operators it has. They check for absent attribute (i.e. null XAttribute) automatically where it makes sense, so you don't have to. I.e. instead of ...`.Attribute("foo").Value`, write `(string)`...`.Attribute("foo")` - and then check value for `null` to see if attribute was missing. Note also that it has overloads for both nullable and non-nullable versions for types such as `int`

Answer (score 0):

I created a class called Applicant, with a property of type `Dictionary` with key `string` and value another `Dictonary<string, string>`

```
public class Applicant {
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> NameValueGroup { get; set; }
}
```

To fill this property I do this.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
Applicant applicant = new Applicant();

applicant.NameValueGroup = document.Element("Applicant").
                            Descendants("NameValueGroup").
                            ToDictionary(keyElement => keyElement.Attribute("attribute").Value, valueElement => valueElement.Descendants().
                                 ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("desc").Value, e => e.Attribute("value").Value));
```

Please excuse the bad formating. It's hard to make that query nice to look at!